# Looking for best jQuery approach to wrap tables

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to wrap a div around any table below a certain class like that:

```
$(".my-class table").wrap('<div style="padding:5px;border-width:5px;border-color:#F2F7FB;border-style:solid;width:80%"/>');
```

Problem is that sometimes I'll have nested tables below this class and I only want to wrap this div once. So, what would be the best jQuery approach here? Search for nested tables or perhaps apply this only to the most inner table? Any ideas will be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use immediate [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) (`>`):

```
$(".my-class > table").wrap('<div style="padding:5px;border-width:5px;border-color:#F2F7FB;border-style:solid;width:80%"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

To wrap just the innermost table, you can do:

```
$(".my-class table").each(function() {
    if(!$(this).has('table')) {
        $(this).wrap(...);
    }
});
```

To wrap just the outermost one:

```
$(".my-class table").first().wrap(...);
```